# Expect/Exp_Send Only works with two expects in a row

Tags: tcl, expect

I have an tcl script that is supposed to send a grep command to a server, but will only execute the command if I put another expect with exp_send immediately after.

```
set spawn_id [::SshLibrary::connect **.***.**.*** username password] ;#just ssh, essentially 
set cmd "grep \"$str\" /var/log/syslog/$smtsIp"
expect -re $::LinuxLIbrary::prompt { exp_send "$cmd\r"}
expect -re $::LinuxLibrary::prompt { exp_send "echo \" \"\r }
...
```

So, through experimentation, I've found out that the first expect will only exp_send its command if the second expect statement is present (Similarly for the second expect command, regarding the presence of the first) even though they expect the same thing and the second statement is entirely useless. I'm unsure of what the problem is, it seems totally illogical. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first command was sent and the resulting string was received successfully. But the returned string is kept in the buffer until you call another 'expect'. It's a common situation with buffered I/O.
Try the second 'expect' without the exp_send.